# Android Studio 2.2 mac version doesn't show red error messages in Logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error, android-logcat

Since I've upgraded my Android Studio to version 2.2, the Logcat stopped showing me the red errors with the point to the lines of code that contain the error, with with older version I could always get them, which helped me a lot with debugging. 
Now if an app encounters some error it just stops and both Android Monitor and Run tabs show me "Application terminated" only, no mention to any error.

Is there something I can fix on Preferences?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your application selected?

Comment: @MuratK. yes, "Verbose" - "Show only selected application" in the Android Monitor